# Converting .wav (CCITT A-Law format) to .mp3 using LAME

Tags: conversion, mp3, wav

I would like to convert wav files to mp3 using the lame encoder (lame.exe). The wav files are recorded along the following specifications:

Bit Rate: **64kbps**
Audio sample size: **8 bit**
Channels: **1 (mono)**
Audio sample rate: **8 kHz**
Audio format: **CCITT A-Law**

If I try to convert such a wav file using lame, I get the following error message:

```
Unsupported data format: 0x0006
```

Could anyone provide me with a command line string using lame.exe that will enable me to convert these kind of wav files?

Comment: what command line are you using currently?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use SoX to convert the A-law input data to a more standard PCM data for LAME to process.

```
sox -A -c 1 -r 8000 input.8khz-mono-alaw.wav ouput.wav
```

Now output.wav should contain standard PCM WAV data.  Run your LAME command on this (add whatever options you like):

```
lame output.wav output.mp3
```

Or, pipe the SoX output into LAME directly:

```
sox -A -c 1 -r 8000 input.8khz-mono-alaw.wav - | lame - output.mp3
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. I was incorrectly using -e signed-integer instead of -e a-law (your -A argument for older version of sox).

Comment: And I'd like to recommend **not** piping sox to lame, as you may get missing header information since sox waits for the file to close before writing certain headers.

Answer (score 0):

download and compile libsndfile I used version 1.0.17
download the source for lame and then use this configure setting

```
./configure --with-fileio=sndfile
```

then

```
make && make install
```

now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/conversion-from-wav-through-cdr-to-mp3-881958/) the answer that worked for me:

> I converted my WAV files using the following commands:
>
> sox file.wav file.cdr
>
> sox -t cdr file.cdr -t wav - | lame -b 32 -m mono - file.mp3
>
> These commands produce with my WAV files MP3 files in 32 kbit/s, 22050
>   Hz mono format. The parameters of the lame command are customized to
>   produce the files similar to the files produced by the command
>   mentioned in the former post:
>
> sox file.wav file.mp3
>
> On my machine the command:
>
> sox file.wav file.mp3
>
> converts WAV files in 23 minutes producing 130 MB of MP3 files.
>
> and the commands:
>
> sox file.wav file.cdr sox -t cdr file.cdr -t wav - | lame -b 32 -m
>   mono - file.mp3
>
> convert WAV files in 39 minutes producing 131 MB of MP3 files.
>
> First method is faster but requires patched sox.